# cacading dropdown showing undefined result in 2nd dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My cacading dropdown is showing undefined result in 2nd dropdown.
Here is my View where I added the 2 dropdown. Basically I want  that when I select branch from branch dropdown then related class must be shown in class dropdown.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BranchID, Model.BranchList, new { @class = "input-class",@id="bid" 
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ClassID, Model.ClassLists, new { @class = "input-class" ,@id="Cid"})
```

here i am making Ajax Call

```
$("#bid").change(function () {
  $("#Cid").empty();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("../AssignSubjToTeacher/GetClass/")',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { id: $("#bid").val() },
    success: function (classes) {
      $.each(classes, function (i, class) {
        $("#Cid").append('<option value="'+ class.Value'">'+class.Text + '</option>');
      });
    },
    error: function (ex) {
      alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
    }
  });
  return false;
})
```

Here is controller code

```
public JsonResult GetClass(Models.SubjAssignToTeacherModel  DisplayRecord, string id)
{
  List<ClassList> objAddclass = new List<ClassList>();
  objAddclass = GetDropDownListclassGet(id);
  SelectList objListOfclass = new SelectList(objAddclass, "ID", "Name",0);
  DisplayRecord.ClassList = objAddclass;
  return Json(DisplayRecord, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Check in the console by applying this `success: function (classes) { console.log(classes);` that when you select first drop its returning proper data.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error at the below line:

```
$("#Cid").append('<option value="'+ class.Value'">'+class.Text + '</option>');
```

should be:

```
$("#Cid").append('<option value="' + class.Value + '">' + class.Text + '</option>');
```

If this doesn't resolve the 'undefined' - Is the returned data (classes) as expected?

As per comments:

```
$.each(classes.ClassList, function (i, class) {
    $("#Cid").append('<option value="'+ class.ID +'">'+ class.Name +'</option>');
});
```

Comment: when i use console.log(classes);this is what i see in console                "Object { ID: 1, BranchID: 0, ClassID: 0, SectionID: 0, BranchName: null, ClassName: null, SectionName: null, BranchList: null, ClassList: Array[29], ClassLists: null, 2 more… }"

Comment: #Mackan not resoloved

Comment: That's not what you should get, if you want a select list. You seem to have the select-elements in the "ClassList" array of the returned object though. Then you'd have to iterate "classes.ClassList" instead of "classes". Try @Stephens answer instead, as there is no need to return the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

Change you controller method to

```
public JsonResult GetClass(string id)
{
  var data = GetDropDownListclassGet(id).Select(c => new { ID = c.ID, Name = c.Name });
  return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and then in the ajax success function

```
success: function (classes) {
  $.each(classes, function (i, class) {
    $("#Cid").append('<option value="'+ class.ID'">'+class.Name + '</option>');
  });
}
```

Comment: not resoloved again undefined is shown in dropdwon now console.log(classes); is showing this                                        TypeError: class  is null 
Object { ID: 2, BranchID: 0, ClassID: 0, SectionID: 0, BranchName: null, ClassName: null, SectionName: null, BranchList: null, ClassList: Array[1], ClassLists: null, 2 more… }

Comment: Obviously you are not using the code in my answer (or what you claim is impossible) Check the value of `data` in the controller method.

Comment: # Mackan thanks u very much its working  with this  answer                    $.each(classes.ClassList, function (i, class) {
    $("#Cid").append('<option value="'+ class.ID +'">'+ class.Name +'</option>');
});

Comment: That's because you are still using that awful and pointless code from your original controller, not the correct code that I showed.